# How can you use XSS to break this security on a site?

Tags: authentication, xss

To delete your account on a website, the following form is used:

```
<form action="/deleteaccount" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<logged-in-username>"></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="cookie" value="<user's-login-cookie>"></input>
  <input type="submit" value="Delete"></input>
</form>
```

And `/deleteaccount` is implemented as:

```
if request.parameters['loginCookie'] == request.cookies['loginCookie'] and validateLoginCookie(request.parameters['user'],request.cookies['loginCookie']):
    deleteAccount(request.parameters['user'])
else
    ...
```

How can a malicious user use XSS to delete someone's account?

I know how XSS works, by injecting malicious script into a browser and sending it to a user, but I don't understand how it can be used in this case. In cases where I've seen XSS, it's usually been within a search form. How can it be used in this case?

Comment: Why do you think that there is an XSS vulnerability here?

Comment: @AbeMiessler The practice exam that this came from says to explain how XSS can be used to perform an attack. Is this not possible?

Comment: Based on what is here, I don't think you can say whether there is or isn't an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Are you sure it is XSS and not CSRF?

Comment: @schroeder yes. How could CSRF be used on a similar model?

Comment: @Jack: As there are no anti CSRF tokens in your form, you could easily copy the entire form to you "attackers website" and execute the form when a user visits the "attackers website". Have a look at the picture here: https://www.nerdbox.it/articles/web-application-security/cross-site-request-forgery-csrf/ on how a CSRF attack works.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an XSS *anywhere* on the site, an attacker can take any action the user could take. In this case the attacker could add an iframe to the vulnerable page, the iframe would have a source of `/deleteaccount` and then the attacker fire the click event on the submit button.